# Java assertion does not fire in some cases with futures

Tags: java, task, future, assertion

I can't seem to get java assertions to fire when used inside futures.

As can be seen in the example below, I create a a list of a single task, which i then execute with .invokeAll. It outputs the string, but even when ran with `-ea` the assertion does not fire.
It does however fire, if I exchange `ex.invokeAll(test)` with `ex.invokeAll(test).get(0).get()`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        var ex = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        List<Callable<Void>> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add(() -> {
            System.out.println("I run");
            assert false;
            return null;
        });
        ex.invokeAll(test);
    }
}
```

I am running this from the commandline using java 11.0.1

Comment: You should not use `assert`, as this is considered very legacy indeed.

Comment: @JoeC I use it to verify some invariants when developing, and while legacy indeed, I would imagine that they still are supported.

Comment: Try adding `Thread.sleep(999);` to the end of your main method.

Comment: @Bohemian no dice. I still don't get an `assertionError`.

Comment: @JoeC care to explain why `assert` is considered legacy? I could not find any references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect.

The behaviour seen (if I exchange ex.invokeAll(test) with ex.invokeAll(test).get(0).get()) is expected. The future is a representation of the result of an asynchronous operation, but you need to actually first access that result using get(). Per the documentation of Future ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get() ), if you try and get the result of the execution and the execution threw an exception, then an `ExecutionException` will be thrown to signal that something went wrong inside the future. Until you call `get()`, you won't get anything.

Comment: According to documentation(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-), `invokeAll` does block until all tasks are completed, either by finishing or throwing. What is puzzling to me, is why it seems to "eat" the exception, or not run the assertion at all, if you don't call ``get()` on the future.

Comment: The code does run, but the exception is stored as the 'result' of the future. You need to access to result to figure out if its a success or if it caused an exception somehow. This is what the contract of the executorservice specifies.

Comment: @Kiskae Oh wow! That was a misunderstanding on my part, but that is indeed the case. If i throw directly inside the task, it will also just finish.